# text becomes number after split in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

When I use SPLIT function, the data in my cell gets converted from TEXT to Number (notice the preceding '0' in cell C3 is removed).

[image]

is there a way to retain the data as Text after the split (or at least retain the 0 in front) ?

```
=SPLIT( JOIN("!",B1:B), "!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When entering a string that looks like a number, one can keep it as a string by preceding it with a single apostrophe `'` (which does not become a part of the string). Same thing works in formulas:

```
=split(substitute("'" & B1, "!", "!'"), "!")
```

This appends ' at the beginning and after each separator (which has to be done before splitting). After splitting, the result is as desired: strings, no leading apostrophe.